# How to sum from different based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two tables Plans and Plandetails

what I want to do is selecting sum the price from Plandetails based on

PlanNo, Current Date, FileNo from Plans

I came up with something like this but it doesn't seem to work correctly

please keep in mind that there is also a column date in plandetails with a possibility of having the current date as well.

for example

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFJih.png

in other words I want to sum the price for all plans based on the current date in table plans

lets say planno 6 and 7 both have the same date which is today, I want to sum the price from plandetails to have a total of 470

> Select price from clinic.plandetails where planno in (Select planno from clinic.plans WHERE date=curdate() and fileno = '" & fileno.Text & "'

thanks in advance.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: 1) include the schema of the tables involved in your question 2) use the MySQL.Data [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) to parameterize your query, as is you are exposed to sql injection

Comment: attached a screen shot of an example

Answer (score 0):

If have made a Sample with more Field in the Reult. You can remove from SELECT if you dont want to have.

I Donr know how to put a String in VB into the Query. YOU MUST CHANGE IT !!

```
SELECT p.PlanNo, CURDATE(), p.FileNo, SUM(pd.price)  
FROM clinic.plans p
LEFT JOIN clinic.plandetails pd ON pd. planno = p. planno
WHERE pd.`date` = curdate() 
AND p.fileno = 'fileno.Text';
```

I hope it help a bit

I have tested again. it look good. see sample

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use clinic
Database changed
MariaDB [clinic]> select * from plans;
+--------+--------+------------+
| planno | fileno | date       |
+--------+--------+------------+
|      5 |      2 | 2016-04-22 |
|      6 |      2 | 2016-04-22 |
|      7 |      2 | 2016-04-22 |
+--------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [clinic]> select * from plandetails;
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| id | planno | fileno | price |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 |      6 |      2 |    80 |
|  2 |      6 |      2 |    90 |
|  3 |      7 |      2 |   100 |
|  4 |      7 |      2 |   100 |
|  5 |      7 |      2 |   100 |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [clinic]> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(p.PlanNo)  SEPARATOR  ', ') , CURDATE(), p.FileNo, SUM(pd.price)
    -> FROM clinic.plans p
    -> LEFT JOIN clinic.plandetails pd ON pd. planno = p. planno
    -> WHERE p.`date` = curdate()
    -> AND pd.fileno = '2';
+---------------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(p.PlanNo)  SEPARATOR  ', ') | CURDATE()  | FileNo | SUM(pd.price) |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+
| 6, 7                                              | 2016-04-22 |      2 |           470 |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [clinic]>
```

Comment: the code works but gives wrong total values to clarify more please see the following table http://imgur.com/fjS0EVy.jpg

lets say planno 6 and 7 both have the same date which is today, I want to sum the price from plandetails to have a total of 470

Comment: Can you please test for me: change SUM(pd.price) to pd.price and run again. so it will display all selected rows. and post the result

Comment: i have add a sample in my answer

Comment: Ok after doing so, all FileNos available came up, after changing pd.fileno to p.fileno it gave the correct FileNo, now its showing prices for other dates a screenshot of the result. http://imgur.com/WPnJEfM PlanNo (11,12,13,14) with date of today, others are not

Comment: @Jack Smith - see my answer, i have add a sample. !! WHERE pd.`date` is wrong. it must WHERE p.`date`

Comment: Sorry I just saw it, ok I did it, it gave me the following result http://imgur.com/5SW6jus which is not correct! it should have given me the following PlanNos http://imgur.com/tFdijET with a total of 115 http://imgur.com/u0OL1CY your code keeps taking the date from plandetails which is not what I want, I want only the date from Plans to be checked. Thanks a lot for your help.